# React-Flux: how to integrate constants?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frameworks, constants, flux

What's the best strategy for handling constants in a React-Flux app?

Currently we define global variables and use them reluctantly within the components. This feels wrong and technically means we shouldn't be using PureRenderMixin even though we're sure the value aren't changing. Is there a best practice like defining a ConstantsStore?

Comment: Are you using a module system, like ES6 modules with Babel or TypeScript? That would be the way to go IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want to use constants for in my opinion. For example if I want to use constants to configure a component I usually export them together with my component for example.

```
import Alert from 'components/Alert';

...

render() {
    return <Alert type={Alert.TYPES.WARNING} />;
}
```

Or I could do

```
import Alert, {TYPES} from 'components/Alert';

...

render() {
    return <Alert type={TYPES.WARNING} />;
}
```

do you have a specific use case?